# Symfony2/Twig jquery extends template

Tags: jquery, templates, symfony, twig

I have the problem with extends template, css works all the time, but I have a problem with jquery if I don`t have extends template, jquery is works, but if I have extends template, jquery is doesn`t works , this is a strange...

```
index.html.twig
```

http://pastebin.com/uBxZebHX

```
index2.html.twig
```

http://pastebin.com/n3Dr8xBq

If I add {% extends 'BloggerBlogBundle:Admin:index.html.twig' %} , everything works, except jquery... ;/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple just call {{ parent() }} in the javascripts block in Child template

```
{% block javascripts %}
        {{ parent() }}
```

{% endblock %}

Because when you call the block in the child template and it's override the content of the parents block instead you call this {{ parent }}

I Hope thaht i'd understant the scenario of your page. if not just tell.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nWaEFKcc

something like this? Doesn`t work...

I try override template sonata admin bundle , everything works except jquery...

Comment: This {{ parent() }} is unnecessary because your parent javascriptss block content nothing "index.hmtl.twig" .Are you sure that your files exists?? Jquery-ui and jquery.min.js. what do you see on your Javascript console in firebug or web developpment tool?

Comment: if I dont have extends template, jquery is works, but if I have extends template, jquery is doesnt works, css works always, so the file is exist, but I check in google chrome console jquery is exist...

Comment: In this step i can't tell something more but you must read your code aigain to check all.. But normally must it work.